# Почему laravel нужен ide helper, а symfony нет?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

В чем принципиальная проблема?

Comment: У laravel много магии, которая скрыта за слоем абстракции. Поэтому нужно генерировать специальный файл, который помогает понять ide где что.

Comment: Чисто в теории ничего не мешает разработчикам IDE самостоятельно написать скрипты по генерации мета-файлов. Но они этого ещё не сделали, вот и используем ide-helper. А для Symfony сделали

Comment: Это риторический вопрос. А почему IDE в ахуе от Magento, и надо поставить кучу патчей что-бы IDE хоть как-то заработала. `Чисто в теории ничего не мешает разработчикам IDE самостоятельно написать скрипты` Слава те господи что они так не делают... Тащить нормальным людям в коробку хлам которым они некогда не воспользуются.

Comment: @EugeneX Можно добавить поддержку фреймворка в качестве расширения IDE. Собственно, сейчас так и сделано. Если нормальным людям оно не нужно, то они и не узнают о нём

Comment: Хорошо что они так не делают... Есть плагины, хочешь ставь... Даже в Sublime есть полноценный набор плагинов для работы как PHP IDE для Laravel. Я раньше тоже работал брался за всё подряд, вордпрессы, ларавелы, магенто. Под каждый приходилось крутиться вертеться. С возрастом понимаешь что это всё полный отстой и стремишься к сольному проекту. И платят намного больше, и мозги себе не насилуешь макаронами.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel использует фасады для доступа к классам из контроллеров, представлений и т.д. Это проблемка для IDE по части автоматического завершения кода (code completion), так как фасады являются обертками над классами и не позволяют IDE распознавать доступные методы классов. Для того чтобы решить эту проблему, Laravel дают IDE Helper, который содержит все доступные методы для каждого класса. Собственно, они и используются средой разработки для автоматического завершения кода и проверки синтаксиса.

Symfony использует контейнер с набором всех сервисов и их зависимостей. IDE может автоматически загрузить этот файл и использовать его для авто завершения кода. Получается что  сервисы и классы фреймворка явно объявлены и доступны.

Других приниципиальны проблем вроде как нет.